# Do we have any site for questions related to Web Data Mining

Tags: discussion, support, site-recommendation

I couldn't find any SO or SE site where I can ask question related to Web Data Mining, can someone guide me in right direction please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might just need to narrow the focus of your question.  There are over 800 [data-mining](/questions/tagged/data-mining) questions on Stack Overflow.  Try your question there if it's programming related.  If it's about analyzing data you can ask on the statistics site, [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I guess "Cross Validated" suits my question better, ta